# Acomodar en linea el menu con el logo en html

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando una pagina web con boostrap 4.6 pero tengo un detalle al momento de querer alinear el logo con el menu cuando visualizo la pagina web con un monitor grande ambos se acomodan perfectamente pero si lo visualizo con la pantalla de la laptop el menu queda debajo del logo y checacando en inspeccionar elemento veo que el logo tiene como un espacio que no permite colocar el logo como lo muestro en la imagen.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- font awesome cdn -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
      <!-- style.css -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/miestilo.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
        /// some script
    
        // jquery ready start
        $(document).ready(function () {
          // jQuery code
    
          //////////////////////// Prevent closing from click inside dropdown
          $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
    
    
        }); // jquery end
      </script>
    
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
    
          <div class="col-md-12 navbar ">
            <a href="index.html" class="logo navbar-brand  offset-md-1"><img src="img/logo.png" width="40.33%"
                height="40.33%" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""></a>
    
            <ul class="nav ml-auto text-white">
              <li class="nav-item "> <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#">Inicio </a> </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown"> Servicios </a>
    
                <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu " role="menu">
                  <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-3 ">
                      <div class="col-megamenu">
                        <h6 class="title text-uppercase text-danger font-weight-bold text-center">Sistemas</h6>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider text-danger p-0"></div>
                        <ul class=" submenu p-0">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Software</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Hardware</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Servicios</a>
                        </ul>
                      </div> <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                    </div><!-- end col-3 -->
    
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="col-megamenu">
                        <h6 class="title text-uppercase text-danger font-weight-bold text-center">Telecomunicaciones</h6>
                        <div class="padre">
                          <div class="dropdown-divider text-danger"></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="p-0">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Redes</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Enlaces</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Enlace Satelital</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cableado Estructurado</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Infraestructura</a>
                        </ul>
                      </div> <!-- col-megamenu.// -->
                    </div><!-- end col-3 -->
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="col-megamenu">
                        <h6 class="title text-uppercase text-danger font-weight-bold text-center">Energías Renovables</h6>
                        <div class="padre">
                          <div class="dropdown-divider text-danger"></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="p-0">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Energía Solar</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Calculo fotovoltaico CFE</a>
                        </ul>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                      <div class="col-megamenu">
                        <h6 class="title text-uppercase text-danger font-weight-bold text-center">Telefonía</h6>
                        <div class="padre">
                          <div class="dropdown-divider text-danger"></div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="p-0">
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telefonía Convencional</a>
                          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Telefonía IP</a>
                        </ul>
                      </div> 
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div> 
    
              </li>
    
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-uppercase" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Experiencia Laboral</a>
    
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Proyectos relevantes</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Certificaciones</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Galería</a>
    
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#"> Distribuidores </a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#"> Contacto </a></li>
              <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#"> Mesa de ayuda </a></li>
    
    
            </ul>
    
    
          </div>
    
          <!-- slider banner     -->
    
          <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="Diseño(4).png" class="bg img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>SLIDE ONE</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="Diseño(3).png" class="bg img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>SLIDE TWO</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="Diseño(1).png" class="bg img-fluid " alt="...">
                <div class="info">
                  <h1>SLIDE THREE</h1>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
    
          <div class="col-md-12">
     
              <p data-aos="fade-up" class="text-black font-weight-light display-2 p-5 text-center">¿Qué hacemos?</p>
              <hr>
            
            
            <div class="boxesContainer p-5">
    
              <div class="cardBox ">
                <div class="card border border-primary rounded ">
                  <div class="front">
                    <h3>Card One</h3>
                    <p>Hover to flip</p>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="back ">
                    <h3>Back Side One</h3>
                    <p>Content in card one</p>
                    <a href="#">Button 1</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="cardBox">
                <div class="card border border-primary rounded ">
                  <div class="front">
                    <h3>Card Two</h3>
                    <p>Hover to flip</p>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <h3>Back Side Two</h3>
                    <p>Content in card two</p>
                    <a href="#">Button 2</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="cardBox">
                <div class="card border border-primary rounded ">
                  <div class="front">
                    <h3>Card Three</h3>
                    <p>Hover to flip</p>
                   
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <h3>Back Side Three</h3>
                    <p>Content in card three</p>
                    <a href="#">Button 3</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
              <div class="cardBox">
                <div class="card border border-primary rounded ">
                  <div class="front">
                    <h3>Card Four</h3>
                    <p>Hover to flip</p>
                    
                  </div>
                  <div class="back">
                    <h3>Back Side Four</h3>
                    <p>Content in card four</p>
                    <a href="#">Button 4</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
      
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
        <script>
          AOS.init();
        </script>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

> El codigo anterios es el codigo html del menu con el logo que se vera como la imagen que adjunto abajo.

[image: asi se ve el logo y el menu en una pantalla de laptop]

```
/*google font*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,700,800,900&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
}
.logo{
    letter-spacing:10px;
}
.navbar{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
    padding:25px 0;
}

.navbar ul.nav{
    margin-right: 5%;
}
.navbar ul.nav li.active,
.navbar ul.nav li:hover{
    background:#dc3545;

}

a.nav-link {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.dropdown-item {
  color: black;  
}
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: #dc3545;  
}

.dropdown-divider {  
  border-top: 4px solid #dc3545;

}

@media all and (min-width: 992px) {
  
  .navbar .has-megamenu{position:static!important;}
  .navbar .megamenu{left:0; right:0; width:100%; padding:20px; background-color: white;  }
  .navbar .nav-link{ padding-top:1rem; padding-bottom:1rem;  }
 
}
```

Comment: Por favor, añade la estructura completa del HTML junto con el CSS si es que falta algo más.

Comment: ya logre colocar el html completo el css que mostre es todo lo que utilizo para el menu

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que el contenedor del logo este ocupando mas espacio de lo que debería, o podría ser también el margin se me ocurre, la clase .navbar-nav también cambia de orientación según la resolución creo, si podrías pasar el código html mucho mejor asi puedo ir probando y te digo que puede ser o al menos si es que encontrara una solucion

Comment: hola arguel se me dificulta poner el codigo me marca errores en la publicacion.

Checare ese dato que me pasaste.